# Swagger 1.5.22 is it possible to add /swagger.json to the swagger output?

Tags: java, swagger

I'm trying to expose swagger.json in the resulting swagger `JSON` or `YAML` output.  This might be a strange request but this is because of the following infrastructural setup.

`Internet > Azure APIM > Internal Websphere setup`

The Azure APIM has allowed firewall rules to contact the internal WebSphere setup.  The internet does not

`Internet > Internal Websphere`

All calls will fail with 404, not founds. Our application is running on the Internal Websphere setup and `/swagger.json` is reachable there. This works for the `APIM setup` however our confluence is running as a cloud solution and needs to get access to the `/swagger.json` for documentation purposes.

The only way I can make this happen is if `/swagger.json` is reachable on the APIM and I just can't find a way to add it to the output.  **I tried** with the following

```java
public ApiRestApplicatie() {
    BeanConfig beanConfig = new BeanConfig();
    beanConfig.setBasePath("/myapplication/api/v1");
    beanConfig.setResourcePackage("be.company.application.rest.resources,io.swagger.jaxrs.listing");
    beanConfig.setPrettyPrint(true);
    beanConfig.setScan(true);
}
```

however, I noticed the following in `ApiListingResource`

```
@GET
@Produces({"application/json", "application/yaml"})
@ApiOperation(
    value = "The swagger definition in either JSON or YAML",
    hidden = true
)
public Response getListing(@Context Application app, @Context ServletConfig sc, @Context HttpHeaders headers, @Context UriInfo uriInfo, @PathParam("type") String type) {
    return StringUtils.isNotBlank(type) && type.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("yaml") 
           ? this.getListingYamlResponse(app, this.context, sc, headers, uriInfo) 
           : this.getListingJsonResponse(app, this.context, sc, headers, uriInfo);
}
```

The operation is hidden and I have no idea if I can override that hidden flag.  Has anyone got any idea of how I could proceed on this?  Maybe add it manually in

```
@SwaggerDefinition(
        info = @Info(
                description = "Rest api emulating the customer portal api",
                version = "2.0.0",
                title = "My Application",
                termsOfService = "http://www.company.be/terms.html",
                contact = @Contact(
                        name = "company",
                        email = "info@company.be",
                        url = "http://www.company.be"
                ),
                license = @License(
                        name = "Apache 2.0",
                        url = "http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0"
                )
        ),
        consumes = {"application/json"},
        produces = {"application/json"},
        schemes = {SwaggerDefinition.Scheme.HTTPS}
)
public interface MyApplicationApiConfig {
}
```

If that is at all possible I'm still experimenting but could use some insights.